# Windows Server Manager on VM cannot connect to Hyper-v host

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-access, windows-server-2019

Here's what's going on: I've got a Windows 2016 Hyper-V host in a workgroup, and a Windows 2019 VM running on that host. VM is part of a domain -- AD is on a second VM on same host.

In the 2019 VM I'm trying to add the hyper-v host to Server Manager. I go to DNS tab, I put in IP of the host, and it finds it. After I add it it lists it by name in Server Manager's All Servers list, but for some reason the IP does not show.

I get the following error when it tries to connect:

> Configuration refresh failed with the following error: The metadata
>   failed to be retrieved from the server, due to the following error:
>   WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while
>   using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer . Verify that the computer exists on the network and
>   that the name provided is spelled correctly.

I did add the creds via right-click Manage As.

Remote management is enabled on the host.

I can ping the host IP; if I pinged the host name, it did so via IPv6. Adding the IP to the hosts file let it ping host's name via IPv4.

If it matters, these VMs are running on a internal virtual switch. I could see where that could be the problem, except the host does have an IP in that subnet and is pingable from the VM.

Any ideas?